# Adding unique ID to file upload

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Just looking to add a unique random id to any file uploaded in the event doubles get uploaded.

Is there any way to add that unique generated id to a column in MySQL.

I am getting an error on the move_upload_file line

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {
        $file_results = "";
        
    if (!$_FILES["file"]["name"])
    {
    $file_result = "No File Uploaded or Invalid File 
    Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    echo $file_result;
    }   else {
        
    $file_results .=
    "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"] ["name"] . "<br>" .
    "Type: " . $_FILES["file"] ["type"] . "<br>" .
    "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"] ["size"] / 1024) . "<br>" .
    "Temp file: " .$_FILES["file"] ["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
    'uploads/'.uniquid(rand()).$_FILES['file']['name']);
    echo 'Thank Your For Submitting Your Item! It Will Be Availabel For You To Style With Soon!';
    
    };
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: paste the error please

Comment: It could be a "privilege" error or a "not excisting" error or.... without any error details we cant help you.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function uniquid() in C:\wamp\www\AddItemForm.php on line 27

Comment: The function name must be: uniqid, not uniquid.

Comment: So i am illiterate? (checked to make sure I spelled that right :(

Comment: That is outstanding!!! Thank you so much for catching that!

Comment: Any idea how to then get that unique id into a database?

Comment: @MikEsy Store the unique name in a variable when it's created, use that in the `move_uploaded_file` function and also pass it to the database when saving

Answer (score 1):

For unique filenames in the fileszstem, we have a method called `tempnam`, you can read about it [here](http://php.net/tempnam) and you should use it instead `uniqid` for unique file names.

Using `uniqid` doesn't guarantee that you will get truly random strings, even the documentation says that.

From the manual:

> This function does not create random nor unpredictable strings. This
>   function must not be used for security purposes. Use a
>   cryptographically secure random function/generator and
>   cryptographically secure hash functions to create unpredictable secure
>   IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I think tempnam would be the correct answer here as per Mjh's answer. I've always used:

```
md5( uniqid() . $fileName . rand(0,100);
```

Which so far has not failed me. Md5 for uniform names.